# How to create condition "if element not exist - do smth" by using Nightwatch?

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I have a list of users, presented by table, and I need to search for td element with appropriate value - and if element not exist on current page - click on link to go on another page.
I have no ideas how to do this but I used xpath selector to find element with some value.

Each user presented by "tr" element and contains "td" elements inside:

```html
<tr>
 <td class="break-all">acceptance</td>
 <td>client</td>
 <td class="break-all"></td>
</tr>
```

So, I need to find td element with value = "acceptance", if it's not exist on current page - click on link to go on another page and continue the search.

**I found solution, and it works for me!**

```js
function isActive(client) {
  client.getAttribute("div.right", "class", function (result) {
    if (result.value == "right active") {
      client
        .click("div.icon-caret-right")
        .perform(function () {
          findByText(client)
        })
    } else {
      //Throw error in this case!!!
    }
  })
}

  function findByText(username, client) {
    client.elements("xpath", "//td[text()='" + username + "']", function (result) {
      if (!result.value.length) {
        isActive(client)
      }
    })
  }

  module.exports = findByText;
```

And I just call `findByText(username, client)`.

But now I have another question - how to throw error from `else` statement???

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this, there might be an easier solution though:

```
function findStringInElementsData(elements, stringToFind, callback) 
{
    var counter = 0,
    numberOfElements = elements.value.length;

    elements.value.forEach(function(element){
        browser.elementIdText(element.ELEMENT, function(result){

            // The string was found, return true
            if(result.value === stringToFind) {
                return callback(true);
            } 

            // The string was not found return false
            if(numberOfElements-1 === counter) {
                return callback(false);
            }
            counter++;
        })
    })
}

browser
.waitForElementVisible('td', 2000)
.elements('css selector', 'td', function(elements){

    findStringInElementsData(elements, "acceptance", function(foundString) {

        if(foundString) {
            // The string was found
        } else {
            // The string was not found, click on link to go on another page
        }
    })
})
```

The code above will get all `td` elements and then call the `findStringInElementsData` function which will loop through them to see it their text value is equal to a supplied string ("acceptance" in your case). If the string is found the function will return true, else it will return false.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem? Any problems with the code I supplied?

Comment: I don't know, I will try it soon and leave the comment