# nightwatchJS how to use assert.containsText on a table?

Tags: automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I've just starting using nightwatch and I want to confirm that a table is correctly populated.  From the terminal I can do something like:

`$("div#systemViewTable table tbody tr td.sortable").text()`

and I get a bunch of text. However when I trying the same selector in nightwatch I just get an empty string.  I.E.>

`browser.assert.containsText("div#systemViewTable table tbody tr td.sortable", "some text")`

How can I make this work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have to options:

Because containsText() is used on a single element you can't use it as in you question referencing multiple td elements. Either you use the `table`, `tbody` or set a class name for the table (a class name is required if you have multiple tables on your site since the selector has to be unique), this will however also match the text if it's outside of the td element which you might not want.

Otherwise your option is to get all td elements using for instance [Selenium elements](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#elements) and loop through each of these and compare them to the given string. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35239322/5072503) for an example of how this can be done.